# JSF datatable row selection

Tags: jsf

How to select multiple rows in a JSF datatable?

Comment: Are you using a jsf framework for your datatable (like Primefaces, Icefaces)?

Answer (score 1):

You can either place a checkbox on each row giving it a value of `#{currentRowItem.selected}` or use [`<rich:extendedDataTable>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?c=extendedDataTable&tab=usage)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<Integer, Boolean> selectMap` in the backing bean. (If the key is not model's id and key is a string, create a Map with String, Boolean pair ..)

For every row provide a checkbox `#{backingBean.selectMap[rowvar.selectedId]}` 
You must be able to find the selected values in the map after each selection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use primefaces as follow:

```
<p:dataTable id="tableId" var="data" value="#{myBean.myList}" 
          selection="#{myBean.selectedDTOs}"               
          rowKey="#{data.objectId}">
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
</p:dataTable>
```